# Appropriate filters' setting

Tags: 7, views

I've custom content-type with several fields, e.g. rozdzielczosc1, rozdzielczosc2 and rozdzielczosc3. There are references to the term.

I'm creating the search. Now, I've several filters

[image]

My question is about third group of filters. I created exposed filter for field_rozdzielczosc1 and filters for field_rozdzielczosc2 and field_rozdzielczosc3 inherit values from filter for field_rozdzielczosc_1. When user set the filter value for field_rozdzielczosc1, filters values for another filter (field_rozdzielczosc2 and field_rozdzielczosc3) is the same. It works.

My search

[image]

In my description I ignore the two first group of filters. They work.

When user set "Rodzielczosc" in the search I'd like to choose contents whose field_rozdzielczosc1 or field_rozdzielczosc2 or field_rozdzielczosc3 is equal choosen value.

When user set "Rodzielczosc" and fill in the "title", I'd like to choose what above but only if title of content includes given "title".

When user doesn't set anything I'd like to choose all contents.

As you've seen, I tried something, yet it doesn't work.

Comment: Look at your screenshots. A lot of blank space and letters way to small to read. Please improve them by taking them from site displayed in a smaller window, or paste this data in txt format

Comment: I think sreenshots are noticable, yet I've respected your opinion and I've tried to update my sreenshots. I don't know why, but I've difficulty in it. It's first time when I can't upload an image. I'll try to solve this problem.

Comment: What modules are you actually using? What URLs do these screens represent?

Comment: I use Views and Field group modules. I suppose that only these modules are used in that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Create separate Group of filters and move a "title" filter there.

Maybe also check all OR and AND (but they seems fine for me...)

Comment: I suppose you haven't understood me. "title" was an example. My problem is referred to inappropriate filters in third group. Currently, for field_rozdzielczosc2 and field_rozdzielczosc3 I've got marked first term's value OR second term's value etc., so, it doesn't matter which value is given by user, because I choose all contents. Every content has the property that its field_rozdzielczosc2 has first term's value or second term's value or .. nth term's value. I don't know what should I change to have what I described.

Comment: That answer isn't good.

Answer (score 0):

I think your content type is not properly organized. Have a look at your fields:

```
field_price
field_price_1
field_price_2

field_resolution
field_resolution_1
field_resolution_2
```

Why don't you use `field_price` for all items for sell? If you will have a thousand different products for sell, will you create a thousand fields like `field_price_xxxx` for them?

This is how I would do that:

Content type: `Image`

Fields:

```
field_image
field_price
field_category (term reference)
```

View page showing `fields` from `Image` content type.

Fields:

```
Content: Title
Content: Image
Content: Price
```

Filters criteria:

```
Content: Title (exposed) 
Content: Published (Yes) 
Content: Type (= image) 
Content: Image:height (exposed) 
Content: Image:width (exposed) 
Content: category (exposed)
```

Done!

Notice: There is no fields like: `field_price_1`, `field_price_2` and there is no fields with resolutions (you don't need them).